# vertical-align:text-top; not working in table cell (td) in HTML5

Tags: html

Not sure why but for the life of me I cannot get my text to align on the top of a table cell (td) when the cell before it is wrapping text.

If I write it out in the HTML it works, but unable to get the same effect in my CSS.

Works with HTML:

```
<td style="vertical-align:text-top;">Some Text</td>
```

Doesn't with CSS:

```
table td { vertical-align: text-top; }
```

And I have tried every combination you can think of within my CSS

Comment: I don't see any difference - http://jsfiddle.net/3bAzu/ do you?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Make sure you are not setting "display: block" on the TD elements, as vertical align doesn't work on block elements.  Also, text-top is not the best, and has some cross browser issues.  Use "top" instead.  Try adding this in your stylesheet:

```
table td { 
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top; 
}
```

Comment: Nice, worked great, solved my problem!!! I couldn't find reference to this anywhere. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Works as `style` attributes too; was able to deploy it in a WordPress(.com) post...thanks!